# Building random homeomorphisms of the circle

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, real-analysis, measure-theory, ds.dynamical-systems

Given a positive Borel measure without atoms $\tau$ on the circle $\mathbb T =\mathbb R /\mathbb Z =[0,1)$ , in https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.3423 a  homeomorphism  $h:[0,1)\to [0,1)$ is defined as
\begin{equation}
h(t)=\tau ([0,t))/\tau ([0,1) )%\qquad \mbox{for}\;\; \theta\in [0,1)
\label{h1}
\end{equation}
Specifically they take $\tau$ formally proportional to $ e^{\beta X(t)}dt$ where
$\beta\geq 0$ and  $X$
is the Gaussian Free Field on the circle
i.e. the random field $X$  with covariance $\mathbb E\, X(t)X(t')=-\log |e^{2\pi it}-e^{2\pi it'}|$ (see within the link and https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.1003 for all the rigorous details).

**Questions:**

- Is the map $\tau \mapsto h$ a homeomorphism between some space and the space of homeomorphisms of the circle?
- Can we use this map to define a measure on the space of homeomorphisms of the circle?

Comment: 1. What topologies are you taking on each space?
2. Assume it is, how would you use this to build a measure?

Comment: Anyhow, the construction is false (or at-least inaccurate), taking say the Bernoulli measure over the regular Cantor set, this construction doesn't yield a homeomorphism as it will not be injective (over any subset you ``deleted'' from the Cantor set). The construction must implicitly assume the given measure is ac with respect to Lebesgue and fully supported, this indeed yields a monotone function as $h(t)$.